# Calling scp from net:ssh

Tags: ruby, net-ssh

Here's the setup:

I have server A, which is running my ruby scripts and servers B & C.  I need to be able to transfer files from B to C.

I've experimented with using Net:SCP, but I haven't found a way to set up a transfer between the two remote servers.  The best I've been able to do was go from B to A and then from A to C.

Based on some example code I've seen elsewhere, I'm trying to ssh onto B and call scp from that server:

```
Net::SSH.start(host, user, :password => pword) do |ssh| 
  ssh.exec! "scp /filename user@serverC:/filename" do |channel, stream, data|
    channel.send_data "#{pword}\n"
  end
end
```

This is not working for me.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: Not getting an error, per se.  I'm able to print the data to the screen and I just see "Permission denied" message from server B.  My assumption is that since the request for the password is happening on server C, net:ssh is not able to see it and/or forward it to server A.